# Socket Client and Server Not Working

Tags: vb.net, sockets, client

```
**Server Code**

Dim serverSocket As Socket
Dim clientSocket As Socket
Dim PubIP as String = "82.XX.XX.XX"
Dim LocalIP as String = "192.XX.XX.XX"

Dim byteData(1023) As Byte

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim host As String = Dns.GetHostName
    Dim ip As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host)
    serverSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim IpEndPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(PubIP), 8080) 
    Me.Text = IpEndPoint.ToString
    serverSocket.Bind(IpEndPoint) 'it can't bind public ip but i need public ip to run the client from other pc and connect to server for chating.
    serverSocket.Listen(5)
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnAccept), Nothing)
End Sub

**Client Code**

Dim clientSocket As Socket
Dim byteData(1023) As Byte

Dim PubIP as String = "82.XX.XX.XX"
Dim LocalIP as String = "192.XX.XX.XX"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    clientSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = ipAddress.Parse(PubIP)
    Dim ipEndPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8080)
    clientSocket.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnConnect), Nothing)
End Sub
```

when i run the server with localip, it runs fine and i am only able to connect client from my computer only (where server runs). if i try to run the client from another computer, it won't connect to server.

so i assigned public ip but when i run the program visual studio shows this error:The requested address is not valid in its context.

so i am stuck here. i am only able to connect client if run from my computer but i need to connect the client from my friend pc to my server in my pc.

any alternative ways are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IPAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) instead of a specific IP address to make your server accept connections on all interfaces.

Other then that, since you mention "local" and "public" IP addresses, you need to understand [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT) and [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).